# Playing the same sound rapidly from a single audiosource vs multiple audiosources

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok let me try and explain...

I am making a card game where it plays a sound effect when a card is added to a pile, but during the setup cards are rapidly added to different piles and it breaks if I use a single `Audiosource`

If I play it from a single `audiosource` it seems not to play them all or if it is it's playing them all at once.

**vs**

If I do it by having an `audiosource` on each pile and use that instance of it and hear the different effects played.

I am in the middle of rewriting the game as the first time was a dry run and didn't know what I was going to need and is a bit rough and came across this while trying to streamline the in game audio by having a `GameAudioManager` singleton to handle the audio.

Is there a reason for this and a solution?

*Info*

Sound Effect is a MP3 and 3kb

Delay between effects is 0.01f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was that a AudioSource can only have one instance of itself playing so if it is playing already it is unable to start the new play.

The solution is to either instantiate them as needed or have it on each item and be able to play it from those individual AudioSources.

Hope this helps anyone else coming across this.

Answer (score 0):

Choice is yours actually...
Want them to play sequentially ? one audio source is enough and add pending clips to a queue and dequeue them as the currently playing one finishes.

Want them to play individually, separately as the event happens, regardless of whether another card was just added and its effect was still playing, then you use multiple audio sources.
Here's a starting point for a manager that plays audios individually as they're requested.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameAudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // your singleton pattern here, so assuming you now have an instance.
    public static GameAudioManager Instance;

    // List holds available sources that we can use to play an audio clip.
    List<AudioSource> availableSources = new List<AudioSource>();

    // Immediately plays a clip, if a cached audio source available, uses it, if none, create new.
    public static void AudioPlayOneShot(AudioClip clip, float volume, float pitch, bool loop)
    {
        Instance.StartCoroutine(Instance.StartPlayingOneShot(clip, volume, pitch, loop);
    }

    private IEnumerator StartPlayingOneShot(AudioClip clip, float volume, float pitch, bool loop)
    {
        AudioSource audioSource = GetAudioSource();
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.clip = clip;
        audioSource.volume = volume;
        audioSource.pitch = pitch;
        audioSource.loop = loop;

        audioSource.Play();
        while (audioSource.isPlaying)
            yield return null;

        // Whenever this clip stops, add it back to available cache.
        CacheAudioSource(audioSource);
    }

    private void CacheAudioSource(AudioSource audioSource)
    {
        audioSource.clip = null;
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
        availableSources.Add(audioSource);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an audio source from cached list or creates a new one if none available.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private AudioSource GetAudioSource()
    {
        if (availableSources == null || availableSources.Count == 0)
            return this.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        else
        {
            AudioSource fromCache = availableSources[0];
            availableSources.RemoveAt(0);
            return fromCache;
        }
    }
}
```

Use like

```
GameAudioManager.AudioPlayOneShot(yourClip, yourVolume, yourPitch, loop);
```

Comment: Thanks but this leaves the door open to sound effects happening out of sync with whats happening on screen. Also I am now thinking Unity did something as I am using a new version than I used for the original project.